# Separate zoom factors for the horizontal and vertical direction in iOS UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming, pinchzoom

Is there a simple way to implement separate zoom factors for the horizontal and vertical direction of a UIScrollView?

The standard behaviour enforces a single scale factor for both, which makes sense for many applications (maps, photos, etc.), but certainly not for all (charts, function plots, etc.).